# Progress dialog with thread

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

i am working on list view control in android. when i click on list view item i want one progress dialog box  and after requested data comes i want to stop it

well i put this dialog box in thread  and when thread is stop i want to display another dialog box but it reality its not working it fires error given below

**05-10 15:05:10.607: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(820): Uncaught handler: thread MagentoBackground exiting due to uncaught exception
**05-10 15:05:10.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

My code is like this

```
           Runnable viewQuestions = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                getViewAnswer(answerBean);
            }


        };
       thread =  new Thread(null, viewQuestions, "MagentoBackground");
       thread.start();
       m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);



      protected void getViewAnswer(AnswerBean answerBean) {
          //fetch data code
            if(viewAnswerBeans != null && viewAnswerBeans.size() > 0){
             m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
             viewAndGiveAnswerDialog(viewAnswerBeans);
                             dialogbox.show();

         } else {
             m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
                     dialogBox.show();

         }
      }
```

my problem is this  "dialogBox.show();" wont work it wont display the message

can any one help me regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for these purposes, I suggest you use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are calling a UI component from a non-UI thread. Have a look at the following link

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler

```
private Handler gps_ws_handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
            dialogBox.show();


    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler within your activity.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then inside the getViewAnswer, post a message to it.

```
protected void getViewAnswer(AnswerBean answerBean) {

    //fetch data code


    handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(viewAnswerBeans != null && viewAnswerBeans.size() > 0){
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        viewAndGiveAnswerDialog(viewAnswerBeans);
                     dialogbox.show();

         } else {
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
             dialogBox.show();

         }
    }
});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For background tasks use AsyncTask with ProgressDialog bounded, like it is shown [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

public class YourActivity extends Activity {

```
private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
private Runnable viewOrders;
private ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

    viewOrders = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            loadList();
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "",
            "Get Data...", true);

}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {



            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourList);

            //create here your adapter 

            mListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                        int position, long arg3) {

                    //on item click
                }
            });
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};

private void loadList() {
    try {
        /* Make your request Here
                    The progress Dialog is dismissed automatically after request is  finished */
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}
```

}